# Why increment a pointer casuing crash?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management

i was learning about allocating and releasing memroy in c++ programming.i tried to increment my pointer and then use delete afterward. it crashed ! why is that happening ?

```
int *pint = new int ;
double *pDouble = new double;

*pint = 3;
*pDouble = 3.5; 

pint++;
pDouble++;

delete pint;
delete pDouble;
```

Comment: You can't `delete` what was not `new`ed.

Comment: "I shot myself in the leg. It hurts! why is that happening ?"

Comment: @VTT thank you , that was very clear

Answer (score 6):

## Problem

```
int *pint = new int ;
```

Dynamically allocates a single `int`. Later,

```
pint++;
```

Increments the pointer, not the value. Incrementing a pointer advances the pointer one element, so `pint++` advances the address in `pint` by one `int` to point out of bounds of what was allocated. Attempting to access or `delete` what is pointed at will invoke Undefined Behaviour and will most likely cause the program to crash.

```
pDouble++;
```

has a the same effect, but advances to the next `double`.

## Solution

There isn't much of a solution other than don't do this. If you need to increment a pointer, to iterate through an array for example, make sure you keep a pointer to the original address so that you can release it when you are finished.

Comment: thank you , this is a clear explanation that could help me understand pointer and memory managment